# How can I remove the PERIOD before the number 1 in the output?

Tags: c++

```
cin >> i >> e;
    while ( i <= e){
            cout << "." << i;
            i = i + 1;
}
```

Example:
INPUT: 1 5
OUTPUT: .1.2.3.4.5
EXPECTED OUTPUT: 1.2.3.4.5

Comment: Don't remove it. Don't write it in the first place. Something like `if (i != initial_i) cout << "." << i;` is an easy solution.

Comment: I'm using while loop btw

Comment: Oh WOW! So THAT is what `while ( i <= e)` means! Learn something new every day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but this should do what you're looking for.

```
int main( ) {
    int input{ 0 };
    int count{ 0 };

    std::cin >> input >> count;

    std::cout << input;
    while( ++input <= count ) {
        std::cout << '.' << input;
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: This is not *equivalent* to the original OP's code, as your code always outputs at least one number.